# Comments and sub comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc

I need sub comments to be just below comments I tried in the below manner and it could able to retrieve only first main comment and all its sub comments but couldn't load from second main comments. The logic I used is

```
            MyConnection.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from maincomments", MyConnection);
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string abc1 = dr[0].ToString();
                string abc2 = dr[1].ToString();
                string abc3 = dr[2].ToString();
                string abc4 = dr[3].ToString();
                string abc5 = dr[4].ToString();
                string abc6 = dr[5].ToString();
                string abc7 = dr[6].ToString();

                maincomm.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(abc2 + "<br />" + abc5 + "<br />"));
                cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from subcomments where acc_id=?", MyConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.BigInt, 20).Value = abc1;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string abcd1 = dr[0].ToString();
                    string abcd2 = dr[1].ToString();
                    string abcd3 = dr[2].ToString();
                    string abcd4 = dr[3].ToString();
                    string abcd5 = dr[4].ToString();
                    string abcd6 = dr[5].ToString();
                    string abcd7 = dr[6].ToString();
                    string abcd8 = dr[7].ToString();
                    maincomm.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(abcd3 + "<br />" + abcd6 + "<br />"));
                }
            }
            MyConnection.Close();
```

**In the above code acc_id is serial number of maincomments.**

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are using `dr` to get comments, in the inner loop you overwrite it with the DataReader for getting sub-comments.

You should use different variables for the two (e.g. `drComments` and `drSubComments`)

That's what looks wrong from a functional point of view. My opinion is that there are still some more improvements to be done. After you fix the code I strongly suggest to post this code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some good advices on how to refactor it.